# Changing what to include just in bibliography with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

The verbose styles in Biblatex can be used without a list of references since all bibliographic data is provided on the first citation, as the documentation points out.

But sometimes a list of references is used even with styles like that. I have been in a situation when I did that and wanted the listing to be even more verbose than the citations, for example to have isbn=true there but isbn=false in the citations.

Is that possible? At least there are no options like isbn, url etc. to `\printbibliography` which I think would be a natural way to do it if you were meant to be able to do it. The command `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` is only available in the preamble, so that's not a method to change this right before `\printbibliography`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment `biblatex` does not have an option to execute options more locally than per-entry, per-type and globally. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1209. For a number of options it would be straightforward to allow a more local application of those options (once one has sorted out the conceptual problem of an order of precedence for those options, do they override the globally set and per-entry and per-type options? - thoughts are appreciated), but others have more complex implementations that involve passing information back to Biber.

For your example of `isbn=false,` we can easily get the desired effect if we go via the implementation of that option. It is implemented as a toggle called `bbx:isbn`. We can switch the value of this toggle at pretty much any point in the document.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\AtBeginBibliography{\toggletrue{bbx:isbn}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Lorem \autocite{gaonkar:in}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote 1 Dilip Parameshwar Gaonkar. ‘On Alternative Modernities’. In: Alternative Modernities. Ed. by Dilip Parameshwar Gaonkar. Durham and London: Duke University Press, 2001, pp. 1–23.// References Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar. ‘On Alternative Modernities’. In: Alternative Modernities. Ed. by Dilip Parameshwar Gaonkar. Durham and London: Duke University Press, 2001, pp. 1–23. isbn: 0-822-32714-7.]

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the same result by using `\clearfield` command:

```
 \documentclass[british]{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{babel} \usepackage{csquotes}
 
 \usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
 
 \AtEveryCitekey{%
     \clearfield{isbn}% }
 
 
 \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
 
 \begin{document} \null\vfill Lorem \autocite{gaonkar:in}
 
 \printbibliography \end{document}
```

This allows you to use per type based filter, e.g.:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
\ifentrytype{book,article}{
    \clearfield{isbn}%
    \clearfield{publisher}%
}{}
}
```